# Embed an exp:channel tag into Wygwam

Tags: ee2, wygwam, channel, embeds, tags

Is it possible to put a exp:channel entries tag loop into a wygwam field? Simply placing something, e.g.,

```
{embed="Common/sidebar_people" show_channel="48"}
```

... fails. The "Allow EE Code" plugin I thought was related but after installing it and looking through the php I'm unclear on its purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to wrap your Wygwam field in the [Allow EE Code](https://github.com/EllisLab/Allow-Eecode) plugin tags within your template:

```
{exp:allow_eecode embed="y"}
    {your_wygwam_field}
{/exp:allow_eecode}
```

Comment: A-ha, thanks. It seems that tinyMCE's tidy routine requires that I wrap the embed code in <div></div> unless there's another way to avoid such a block-level wrap?